# How to organise a Scrapy crawler of JavaScript website that should loop over list of elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm currently learning web scraping with Scrapy, and I wanted to scrape the data from a website that uses the JavaScript. I tried to integrate Scrapy with Selenium, but I will also be grateful for the solution that uses Splash, for example.

I can't share the website I'd like to crawl (it requires logging in anyway), but I'll try to describe the setup as accurate as I can.

To access the data I want to scrape, one needs to perform the following steps:

1. Open the website
2. Log in
3. Choose an element from the JavaScript-powered list of elements
4. Choose another element from another JavaScript-powered list of elements
5. Then we hit another list of clickable elements and the goal is to scrape all elements. Unfortunately, to access the data, one needs to click each element and choose the appropriate tab. The operation needs to be repeated for every element of `id='element-3'`. So after accessing a data and scraping it for one element 3 we need to go back, click the subsequent element of `id='element-3'`, access the data tab, scrape it, go back and so on.

In a tutorial I followed, the Selenium actions were specified in `__init__` method and only `driver.page_source` was stored and passed later to `parse` method. However, the content of HTML is changing with each action, and I can't really access the data without clicking on each element in a list. Therefore, I probably need a loop somewhere. And I have no idea how to structure my scraper so that it'll be efficient.

The pseudo code (not a real example!) to mimic all the operation needed to access the data is below. Please note that I extract only the 10th element of the list that should be looped over, while in my desirable solution I want to scrape the data from all the list elements.

```
   import scrapy
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

   class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
        driver.get('https://example.com') # This is not a real URL

        # Logging in to the site (ommited for brevity)

        element1_xpath = "//div[@id='element-1']"
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)) \
            .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element1_xpath))).click()
        
        element2_xpath = "//div[@id='element-2']"
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)) \
            .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element2_xpath))).click()

        element3_xpath = "(//div[@id='element-3'])[10]" # Here, I select only the 10th element, but the goal is to 
                                                        # iterate over all elements found
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)) \
            .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element3_xpath))).click()

        data_xpath = "//div[@id='data-table']"
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10, ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)) \
            .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, data_xpath))).click()

        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr[position()>1]")
        for row in rows:
            print(row)

        self.html = driver.page_source

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Comment: Seems like your need are very specific, is there some chance you can save the html frmo the page you are scraping from, in order to test some possible solutions? (Tip: xpath is the slowest among other finders, so when you have html elements with an ID, use that id)

Comment: I don't think I can grab the whole HTML code as this is a dynamic page and plenty of elements are loaded and hidden with every move/click on the page. But I don't need an exact solution. I'm confused how can I integrate all those dynamic actions within the Scrapy spider. So some pseudocode would do, I believe.

Comment: Just asking, did you check the Chrome's DevTools to see the calls? Ctrl+Shift+i and then click XHR. Maybe, the dynamic data are retrieved in plain json every time you click those buttons

Comment: @jakes I understand. Personally I've never used Scrapy or other tools in addition to Selenium, so maybe my requests are pointless, and my suggestions would be useless to you. If no one will provide a suitable solution, I will be glad to help, but I really need a similar page to work on, otherwise I will just waste your time. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried my best to understand your description. But it is a little bit difficult.

My understanding is that you need to click each element with `id='element-3'`, crawl the data, and go back to the origin page.

In this way, you just need to create two windows and switch between each other. If you need to parse the page source, you just need to save it in a list for further analysis.

Try this:

```
for i in drive.find_element_by_id("element-3"):
     window_1 = driver.current_window_handle
     i.click()
     windows = driver.window_handles
     driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
     data_xpath = "//div[@id='data-table']"
     ........

    self.html.append(driver.page_source)
    driver.switch_to.window(window_1)
```

Because you did not give me the website, I can not check whether it works.

If you have any further problems, feel free to ask me